# FetchXml query generates a 'Generic SQL Error' but works if I switch the linked entities around?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm attempting to query the product catalog of a "vanilla" CRM 2015, my final aim is to retrieve the active products by price list and substring of name, at the moment I'm hard-coding my data as follows:

```
PriceLevel: hardcoded GUID
Name: hardcoded "a"
```

The resulting XML is this:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" count="50">
    <entity name="productpricelevel" >
        <attribute name="uomid" />
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="pricelevelid" operator="eq" uitype="pricelevel" value="{7080964d-85df-e411-80ba-00155d0b0c38}" />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="product" from="productid" to="productid" alias="ac" >
            <attribute name="name" />
            <attribute name="productnumber" />
            <order attribute="productnumber" descending="false" />
            <filter type="and">
                <condition attribute="name" operator="like" value="a" />
                <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

When I attempted to execute the query, I got `Generic SQL Error`. I then looked at the trace logs, and found this:

```
Exception when executing query: select DISTINCT "productpricelevel0".UoMId as "uomid", "productpricelevel0".UoMIdName as "uomidname", 
coalesce("LL0".Label,"ac".Name ) as "ac.name", "ac".ProductNumber as "ac.productnumber"     
from     ProductPriceLevel as "productpricelevel0" join Product as "ac" 
on ("productpricelevel0".ProductId  =  "ac".ProductId and ( coalesce("LL0".Label,"ac".Name)  like 'a' and "ac".StateCode = 0))     
left outer join BusinessDataLocalizedLabel as "LL0" on ("LL0".ObjectId = "ac".ProductId and "LL0".LanguageId = 1033 and "LL0".ObjectColumnNumber = 6 )     
where     ("productpricelevel0".PriceLevelId = '7080964d-85df-e411-80ba-00155d0b0c38') order by
 "ac".ProductNumber asc 

Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The multi-part identifier "LL0.Label" could not be bound
```

In an attempt to identify a pattern, I switched the JOIN around, ending up with this XML:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true" count="50" >
    <entity name="product" >
            <attribute name="name" />
            <attribute name="productnumber" />
            <order attribute="productnumber" descending="false" />
            <filter type="and" >
                <condition attribute="name" operator="like" value="a" />
                <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
            </filter>
        <link-entity name="productpricelevel" from="productid" to="productid" alias="ac" >
        <attribute name="uomid" />
        <filter type="and" >
            <condition attribute="pricelevelid" operator="eq" uitype="pricelevel" value="{7080964d-85df-e411-80ba-00155d0b0c38}" />
        </filter>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

This time, I got my results as expected, no errors.

The organization is new and only contains Sitemap/HTML/JS customizations (the entities I'm querying are not customized yet), 1033 is the base language, there is another language installed and enabled but it isn't used by any of the 2 users of the system.

What's going on in the first case ?

*UPDATE*: The first query *works* against a 2013 organization. This is starting to feel like a bug.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me too :)

Answer (score 3):

This definitely is a bug. I guess Microsoft changed the engine that converts `QueryBase` queries into T-SQL.

This week we had an issue with linked entities. It was about the following condition:

```
.AddCondition("statuscode", ConditionOperator.In, new object[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

When applied on the *primary* entity of a `QueryExpression`, the condition is processed as expected. When applied on a *linked* entity it fails. In previous versions of Dynamics CRM it works in both scenarios.